# Handling key events in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm using Javascript (React JS) to build a component that needs to listen to the left and right arrow keys. My component is a card that has a list of images. When an image is clicked, it is displayed, but I want to be able to hit the right and left arrow keys and navigate images.

I have a bunch of nested divs and I'm trying to figure out which one should have the onKeyPress listener assigned. Right now I have it assigned to many divs, but I don't see an event being fired.

Comment: "Right now I have it assigned to many divs, but I don't see an event being fired" --- divs (*generally*) don't have focus, so cannot emit keyboard events

Comment: I guess you want to bind the event listener to the `document`, just like you usually do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a tabIndex on the docs for keyboard events to be fired. You can then catch this by having an onKeyPress on your list container. Docs can have focus, but you will need to do that in your. ComponentDidMount and you will probably want to track selected cells in your top level list state and pass down isSelected / isFocussed as props (depending on if you want multi select or not)